# Newtonsoft JSON Trying to deserialize part of arrayed json to class

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization, json.net

Below is the json in a very simplified form (the original contains many more items). I want to add the "acf" content of all items to List

```
[{
    "id": 26,
    "date": "2023-08-30T18:36:24",
    "date_gmt": "2023-08-30T18:36:24",  
    "acf": {
        "name": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "age": "33"     
    }
}, {
    "id": 20,
    "date": "2023-06-11T11:17:02",
    "date_gmt": "2023-06-11T11:17:02",
    "acf": {
        "name": "Randy",
        "lastName": "Jones ",
        "age": "22"     
    }
},
{
    "id": 20,
    "date": "2023-06-11T11:17:02",
    "date_gmt": "2023-06-11T11:17:02",
    "acf": {
        "name": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Taylor ",
        "age": "56" 
    }       
}]
```

```
    public class Acf
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is an example of how I tried to solve it. Surely there is a better and simpler way to solve this task. Thank you for your help.

```
  [System.Serializable]
  public class Acf
  {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
  }
 
  private List<Acf> _acfList = new List<Acf>();
 
 
 void PrepareAcfData(string json)
 {
 
 JArray data = JArray.Parse(json);
 
  for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
  {
    Acf newAcf = new Acf();
       
    newAcf.name = data[i]["acf"]["name"].Value<string>();
    newAcf.lastName = data[i]["acf"]["lastName"].Value<string>();
    newAcf.lastName = data[i]["acf"]["age"].Value<int>();
        
        _acfList.Add(newAcf);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you just make another class and deserialize the whole thing directly `class Root { public Acf acf; }` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(json);`

Comment: Because there are a lot of unnecessary elements in the json (the json in the example is simplified so that it is easier to show its structure) and I only need "acf"

Comment: You don't need to add all the other fields, just add the fields you need, exactly like I showed. Side note: you don't need the `Serializable` attribute

Answer (score 1):

You could simply have a wrapper type

```
public class Item
{
    public Acf acf;
}
```

which is the actual JSON format you show us and then do

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
```

instead.

If you then really need to get these as a `List<Acf>` you can either iterate "manually"

```
var acfs = new List<Acf>(items.Count);
foreach(var item in items)
{
    acfs.Add(item.acf);
}
```

or simply use Linq (`using System.Linq;`)

```
var acfs = items.Select(item => item.acf).ToList();
```

or as said simply stick to the `List<Item>` right away in order to avoid all the overhead with creating additional list/enumeration.

You only need to implement those fields/properties you are actually interested in.

see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nihNNY)

Or go for the [anonymous type mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77011983/7111561)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine [`JToken.SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) using a [JSONPath wildcard expression](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) with [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) to simplify your code:

```
var _acfList = root.SelectTokens("[*].acf").Select(t => t.ToObject<Acf>()).ToList();
```

You could also use [anonymous types](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) to deserialize only selected parts of your JSON:

```
var _acfList = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new [] { new { acf = default(Acf) }})
    .Select(a => a.acf)
    .ToList();
```

Notes:

- `[*]` is the JSONPath wildcard operator selecting all items in an array.
- `[*].acf]` selects the value of the property `"acf"` in each array object.
- `ToObject<Acf>()` converts each of those to your final model.
- If your JSON were more complex, say with some outer container object `{"root":[/* The array above*/ ]}`, you could add that in as follows:

  ```
  root.SelectTokens("root[*].acf").Select(t => t.ToObject<Acf>()).ToList();
  ```
- Deserializing directly to anonymous types may be more performant that parsing to an intermediate `JToken` hierarchy.

Demo fiddle for SelectTokens [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NJytio) and for anonymous types [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0cRBRQ).

Answer (score 0):

Just use Linq

```
    List<Acf> _acfList = JArray.Parse(json)
                               .Select(ja => ja["acf"].ToObject<Acf>())
                               .ToList();
```